# How parent and child fields initialized in Inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am facing one confusion.

Here is my small code snippet

```
public class Father {

    public String x;

    public Father() {
        this.init();
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }

    protected void init() {
        x = "Father";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm Father";
    }

    void ParentclassMethod(){

        System.out.println("Parent Class");
    }

}


public class Son extends Father {
    public String x;


    @Override
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("Init Called");

        x = "Son";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm Son";
    }

    @Override
    void ParentclassMethod(){
        super.ParentclassMethod();
        System.out.println("Child Class");
    }

}

public class MainCLass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Son ob = new Son();

}
```

So when I'm creating a Son's class instance which is inherited from Class Father, so JVM automatically calls Father's class constructor. It creates Son type instance when Father's constructor called otherwise Father's fields wont initialized. So far Good..!

As you can see field `x` is derived from Father's class into Son's class.
And my code initializing `x` using `init()` method.

Then why its showing null.

Its very confusing. Can any one explain ?

Comment: _Do not_ call overridable methods from a constructor.

Comment: Try removing the `String x` from Son class and call `super.x="Son"` in `init()` of Son

Comment: Fields are not inherrited, only the instance methods

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java. Since you re-declared `x` inside `Son`, this variable will actually be a *different* `x` than the one in `Father`. So in the `init` method of `Son`, you are initializing the `Son`'s `x`, but *not* the `Father`'s `x`.

On the other hand, your statement `System.out.println(this.x);` is inside the `Father` class so it only knows about `Father`'s `x`. Since you no longer initialize this variable due to overriding the `init` method, the `x` in `Father` remains `null` (the default) and thus it will print `null`.

You can fix the problem by removing `public String x;` from the `Son` class. This will make `Father`'s `x` the only `x`, removing the problem.

However, in general, you want to make this variable `private` instead of `public`. You should also never call a non-`final` method in a constructor. [It can only introduce bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors). The proper way to initialize it in this case would be to have a constructor with a parameter in `Father`:

```
public class Father {
    private String x;

    protected Father(String x) {
        this.x = x;
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }

    public Father() {
        this("Father");
    }

    // Rest of father's code, without the init method
}

public class Son extends Father {
    public Son() {
        super("Son");
    }

    // Rest of son's code, without the init method
}
```

Comment: Can I initialize an inherited filed, which was declared but not initialized in a parent class, without hiding it or anything like that?